# UCS2 coding and decoding using Python

Tags: python, ucs2

```
s = "خالد".encode("utf-16be")
uni = s.decode("utf-16be")
print (uni)
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-7: ordinal not in range(128).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 what you have would work already, because string literals are unicode by default.

In Python 2, you can make a unicode string literal with the `u` prefix.

```
s = u"خالد".encode("utf-16be")
uni = s.decode("utf-16be")
print (uni)
```

Result:

```
خالد
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have an unicode **encode** error with the **ascii** charset. This error should not have been raised on any of your two first lines, because none is trying to encode an unicode string as ascii.

So I assume that it is caused by the `print` in the third line. Depending on your system, and your exact Python version, the `print` will try to encode with a default encoding which happens to be ascii here.

You must find what encoding is supported by your terminal, or if you can use 'UTF-8'.

Then you can print with

```
print(uni.encode("utf-8", errors="replace")) # or the encoding supported by your terminal
```